# How to create 100 random numbers between 1 and 9999 with 4 digits, and place numbers in 10 rows of 10 numbers?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, return

Having an issue figuring out how to get this solved, and I've searched and looked for answers, but they don't resemble what I'm looking for.
This is beginner stuff, I realize but any help would be highly appreciated.

The code below was given by my teacher and it works for creating ***one*** random number. For the life of me I can't figure out how to make this create 100 random numbers and make a 10 x 10 square of them.

```
eg. 5468 2367 1587 2587 2310 9802 0154 8753 4965 2571
    3249 3248 2158 4659 1321 1278 9871 0123 4654 4587
    etc. for 10 rows.

<div id="answer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function giveValues() {
var length, zeroes;
var number = Math.round((Math.random() * 9999));

// toString()-method and lenght to set amount of digts
zeroes = 4 - number.toString().length;

for (var j = 1; j <= zeroes; j++) {
number = "0" + number;
}
return number;
}
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = giveValues();
```

I also know that there is if (j % nameofvar == 0) { for making a new line, but am unable to make that work.

Comment: When you say 10x10 square of them, are you referring to displaying them as your example on the first line? Or in an array?

Comment: Yes, displaying as in the example. I haven't worked with arrays yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you haven't learned arrays yet, try the following as I think it's best inline with what you're looking for. Here is a Plunker as well http://plnkr.co/edit/LltYPtSfR9Ndo46kYmVN?p=preview.

```
<div id="answer"></div>

<script>
  function giveValues() {
    var length, zeroes;
    var number = Math.round((Math.random() * 9999));

    // toString()-method and lenght to set amount of digts
    zeroes = 4 - number.toString().length;

    for (var j = 1; j <= zeroes; j++) {
      number = "0" + number;
    }
    return number;
  }

  var columns = 10;
  var total = 100;
  var bigString = "";

  for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
    if (i != 0 && i % columns == 0) {
      bigString += "<br/>";
    }
    bigString += giveValues(i).toString() + " ";
  }

  var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
  answer.innerHTML = bigString;
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like something I understand and follows the given code as well. Cheers.

Comment: Great, happy to help. Please up vote the answer and press the checkmark on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most basic way:

```js
      function lpad(number) {
    while (number.toString().length < 4) {
        number = "0"+number;
    }

    return number;
}

var max = 9999;

var matrix = [];
var size = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
    if (i % size === 0) {
        matrix.push([]);
    }
    var number = lpad(Math.ceil(Math.random() * max));
    matrix[matrix.length - 1].push(number);
}

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = matrix.join("<br />");
```

```html
<div id = "answer"></div>
```

Using arrays is more effective, but you can also simply concatenate too.

Comment: So is the method that was shown by the teacher overly complicated? I think a key part of this is that the returned value has to be 4 digits. In your answer there are numbers like 47, which should be 0047. I believe that is the point of the toString part.

Comment: Missed the padding at first. Added it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just generate a large random number, and then limit it to 4 digits.

Try this:

```
function giveValues() {
  var number = Math.round((Math.random() * 999999999));
  return number.toString().substr(0, 4);
}
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arr.push([giveValues(), giveValues(), giveValues(), giveValues(), giveValues(), giveValues(), giveValues(), giveValues(), giveValues(), giveValues()]);
}

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = arr.join(' <br/>').replace(/,/g,' ');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moshekarmel1/34spm4hh/